# How to clear "approved" permissions on browser

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I use SSO Microsoft login on my site and Azure AD for configuration server authentication and authorization, I opened my site in browser first time, entered my credentials, approved permissions (first time it was basic permissions) and received access. Later I extended permissions on Azure AD to:
[image]

and I try to get access to profile and receive

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

If I try to open in other browser (first time), it requests more extended permissions and after approving it I get access with profile (as I expects).
How to "clear" approved permissions for browser and init ask permissions again?

I tried to clear cookies for the my site, but it was not enough, only reentering credentials, but not requesting for approving permissions

Comment: @SrideviMachavarapu-MT I have problems on client side, not on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. We can go to [https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?uaid={...}](https://account.live.com/consent/Manage?uaid=%7B...%7D) and remove permissions for this account